# youtube embed does not work on internet explorer although works fine in Chrome

Tags: youtube

I am embedding youtube videos in my website. It works fine in Chrome but in Internet Explorer the iframe is just black with no embedded video.

Comment: in which IE version?

Comment: add you code for more explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug recently introduced by youtube which affects IE version 7, and IE version 8 compatibility mode. It looks like there may be a few workarounds but probably the safest answer is to fall back to the older object/embed code.

for more info check this:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/05jaHASZ1Mo

this might help you.